# Format double to string and show 2 places after first digit occurrence

Tags: c#

What my outcome should look like is something like this:

```
double n1 = 0.024862;
double n2 = 1357512.15;
double n3 = 124.187;
Output:
N1: 0.0248
N2: 1,357,512.15
N3: 124.18
```

This is what i currently have:

```
n1.ToString("#,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

which works for big numbers, but if i have a number like 0.0005524 i will get 0.00 and i would like to have 0.000552

So 2 digits after the first occurrence of a digit

Comment: have you tried using `Math.Round()` ?

Comment: should 1.0005524 also become 1.000552, or 1.000 then? are you sure you meet an actual requirement doing so? the mathematical meaning is no longer that of just rounding.

Comment: 1.0005524 should become 1.00, so for everything greater than 1 i could use the code i posted, but what about everything smaller than 1 (btw negative numbers are not possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
private static string NFiguresAfterFirstDecimal(double d, int figures)
{
    int c = 0;
    while (Math.Abs(d) < 1.0 && Math.Abs(d) > 1E-50){
        d *= 10.0;
        c++;
    }
    d = Math.Round(d, figures) / Math.Pow(10.0, c);
    if (Math.Abs(d) < 1.0 && c > 2)
        return ((decimal) d).ToString();
    else
        return d.ToString("#,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Test run:

```
double[] list = {0.00055243435, 0.00, 0.1, 1357512.157, 1.0001, 1.1, 123.445};

foreach(double d in list)
    Console.WriteLine(NFiguresAfterFirstDecimal(d,2));
```

Output:

```
0.000552
0.00
0.10
1,357,512.16
1.00
1.10
123.44
```

Comment: i changed it to:
`private string NFiguresAfterFirstDecimal(double d)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(d) < 1.0)
            {
                int c = 0;
                while (Math.Abs(d) < 100.0 && Math.Abs(d) > 1E-50)
                {
                    d *= 10.0;
                    c++;
                }
                d = Math.Round(d, 0) / Math.Pow(10.0, c);
                return ((decimal)d).ToString();
            }
            else
                return d.ToString("#,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }`

Is there no more elegant way of doing this?